# wrong display for single quotes with word-break:break-all

Tags: html, css, word-break

```
  <html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<body>
<table style="width:150px; word-break:break-all;">
    <tr>
        <td>'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''</td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

but,the display was wrong(all the single quotes display in one line).I used &apos; instead ,but it did't work.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I just tested in Windows Chrome and cannot replicate the error.

Comment: IE8,and the display is ok when I use other text other than single quotes.

Comment: solved.You can use 'word-wrap' style.word-break is not useful for serial symbol(single quotes etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS: `-ms-word-break: break-all;`

Comment: I think you don't know what I mean.I want to know why single quotes display in one line and how can I make it display in more than one line if it is too long.